# Counting the number of solutions for 2 related equations

Tags: java, algorithm, math, xor

How do I find the number of solutions for

```
s = a+b
x = a^b
```

When `s` and `x` are given, and `^` means `xor`?

So for like `(0,0)` or `(31,31)` or `(15,10)`?

I've tried converting `x` into a binary string but after that I'm unsure where to go with it.

Comment: Is that a power operation or a logical bitwise "and"?

Comment: @LutzL I think it's a XOR.

Comment: its XOR sorry I should of been more specific.

Comment: Do you need to find a single assignment `(a, b)`, or do you need all of them?

Comment: I need to find then all, the number of possible solutions for a and b

Comment: you need a purely logical / math equations to calculate the # of solutions? or can you just write code to count it?

Comment: I can wright code, can't be too brute force heavy else it times out.

Comment: if i manage to get something like s = x^b + b,  can u brute force # of b? (which equals to # of solutions (a,b))

Comment: nope I have a time limit constraint which I don't know what exactly the number is but its probably no more than a second or few seconds.

Answer (score 4):

The method `solution` returns `null` if there are no solutions. If there is a solution, it returns `a` (for just one solution). You can get `b` by doing `s - a` or `x ^ a`.

If a solution exists, the total number of solutions (in `long`) is 2 to the power of `Long.bitCount(x)`.

For example, the solution found for `s = 24`, `x = 6` is `a = 9`, `b = 15`.
In binary:

```
 9 = 1001
15 = 1111
```

These numbers differ in 2 positions, so there are `Math.pow(2, 2) = 4` solutions in total. You can get all possible solutions by interchanging the bits of `a` with the corresponding bits of `b` for some or all of these positions.

This gives 3 further solutions.

```
11 = 1011     13 = 1101     15 = 1111
13 = 1101     11 = 1011      9 = 1001
```

Here is the code:

```
public static Long solution(long s, long x) {
    return recursive(s, x, false);
}

private static Long recursive(long s, long x, boolean carry) {
    boolean s1 = (s & 1) == 1;
    boolean x1 = (x & 1) == 1;
    if ((s1 == x1) == carry)
        return null;
    if ((s == 0 || s == -1) && (x == 0 || x == -1))
        return s;
    Long a;
    if (x1)
        return (a = recursive(s >> 1, x >> 1, carry)) == null ? null : a << 1;
    if ((a = recursive(s >> 1, x >> 1, false)) != null)
        return a << 1;
    if ((a = recursive(s >> 1, x >> 1, true)) != null)
        return 1 + (a << 1);
    return null;
}
```

I decided against writing a method to return a `HashSet` of all solutions, as these sets would, in some cases, be massive. However, you could write a method for generating all possible solutions, without storing them all in memory at once. See, for example, [Generating all binary numbers based on the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584117/generating-all-binary-numbers-based-on-the-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote by v_j the j-th bit of value v with j=0 being the least significant bit.

The key observation is that the arithmetic sum a+b can be expressed in terms of xor operation a ^ b and the carry bits of the addition.
We have

```
s_j = a_j ^ b_j ^ c_j = x ^ c_j
```

where c_j is the carry bit added to j-th position.
To figure out what happens with carry bits, notice that

```
c_0 = 0
c_1 = a_0 & b_0   (so c_1 is one when both a_0 and b_0 are one)
c_j = 1 if and only if at least two of a_j, b_j, c_(j-1) are one.
```

The last condition is essentially saying that

```
c_j = Majority(a_j, b_j, c_(j-1)) = a_j & b_j ^ a_j & c_(j-1) ^ b_j & c_(j-1)
```

Having both a + b and a ^ b you can determine the bits c_j of the carry and from that you should be able to deduce the formula for the number of solutions for each a_j, b_j depending on the values of c_j and c_(j-1).